# Spark SQL : MovingAverage excluding top 10% and bottom 10%

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to find moving average of a timeseries value partitioned by a field "ReportId". I am using the below method to find moving average, but I am facing issues with outlier(anomaly) values which affecting the average value. So I want to exclude the top 10% and bottom 10% values from calculating average.

```
var movingAvgDS = ds.withColumn("MovingAverage", avg(col("ConsumedWatt")).over( Window.partitionBy("ReportId").rowsBetween(-50,50)) )
```

Comment: You won't be able to do something like this with window functions without UDAF or skipping window and using functional API. However operation like this won't scale very well as it will require recomputing quantiles for each frame.

Comment: If you are ok with a two pass algo, then you could possibly use ntile function to add a column with deciles first then filter (>1 && <10) and calculate the average.